# Oracle Developer Script Output

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I read the answer earlier pertaining to my problem but it doesn't solve it. If I run a simple query to view a table, the script output would be in real time, it would come in line by line. I had it in a grid format but can't seem to get it back

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you just want to run as a statement (control-enter) instead of as a script (F5)? Or do you want to open the table from the connection/object browser in the panel on the left, which has a 'Data' tab?

Answer (score 0):

At the top menu bar of your sql developer you have the first big green arrow "run statement", and next to it a document with a smaller green arrow, "Run script".  The "run statement" should produce the grid view, while the "run script" will do the unformatted line by line view.

So sounds like you should be clicking the "run statement" instead, or you could just press "control-enter" on your query.

Comment: Perfect! CTRL-ENTER shows display in grid mode, but I had it mapped to the F5 key